# Flask jsonify: object is not iterable

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a class looking like the following:

```
class Sound(SoundJsonSerializer):
    def __init__(self, name, length):
        self.name = name
        self.length = length
```

where SoundJsonSerializer enabling my custom JSONEncoder to serialize this object into JSON:

```
{
    "name": "foobar",
    "length": 23.4
}
```

Now I want one of my requests to respond exactly with the above JSON.

```
@app.route('/sounds/<soundid>')
def get_sound(soundid):
    s = Sound("foobar", 23.4)
    return jsonify(s)
```

yields an error claiming `s` was not iterable which is true. How do I make the method return my wanted JSON?

I know I can do it by explicitly creating a dict from my `Sound` object like this:

```
    return jsonify({"name": s.name, "length": s.length})
```

But this seems really ugly to me. What's the preferred way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Actually, I would prefer the way that you deem "ugly". If you do this often enough, then perhaps make the creation of the dictionary into a function that takes the object and a list of strings representing the attributes you want included (or perhaps excluded) and create the dictionary (using `dir()` and `getattr()`).

Comment: Yeah this issue is pretty annoying, so I decided to [patch Flask to make it work](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/pull/1209).

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly try this work around:

```
class Sound():
    def __init__(self, name, length):
        self.name = name
        self.length = length

@app.route('/sounds/<soundid>')
def get_sound(soundid):
    s = Sound('foobar', 23.4)
    return jsonify(s.__dict__)
```

Comment: This is not a good practice as it exposes all the class internals, not only the attributes he wants

Comment: @PaoloCasciello is right, there might only be a subset of attributes that I want in the JSON representation. That's what my custom JSONEncoder takes care of.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a couple of different ways. The safest way to ensure that you only return what you want is to do it like this:

```
class Sound():
    name = None
    length = None
    test = "Test"

    def __init__(self, name, length):
        self.name = name
        self.length = length

@admin_app.route('/sounds/<sound_id>')
def get_sound(sound_id):
    s = Sound('foobar', sound_id)
    return jsonify(vars(s))
```

By defining the name = None, length = None as part of the class level variables, you can use the vars() versus the `__dict__`

When you instantiate the class through the `__init__`, and set the variables there, the `jsonify` will only return what you set via the `__init__`.

Result with above code:

```
{
"length": "1",
"name": "foobar"
}
```